# Flutter - work in debug mode but crash in release apk

Tags: flutter, crash, apk, release

I tried to use release apk on Android phone but the app crashed on startup

I’ve tried follow solutions, but it didn’t work

1. set `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` as false
2. change `applicationId` name
3. `flutter build apk --release --split-per-abi --no-shrink`

Here is the plugin list that I used

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
flutter_barcode_scanner: ^2.0.0
intl: ^0.17.0
http: ^0.13.4
shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
device_info: ^2.0.3
```

The Android phone version ⇒ 5

My `flutter build apk` message

```html
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
```

build.gradle

```html
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.transport"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how you know it crashed?

Comment: When I opened the app, only showed a white screen and closed immediately

Answer (score 0):

Add `buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"` to your build.gradle

build.gradle

```
android{
  compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
  buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
}
```

Comment: Tried it but not work. I built it in debug apk and it worked.